# Dependent object in spring

Tags: spring, oop, dependencies

Consider we have two classes, Employee and Address. Employee class has a Address field. in this case which one is dependent object?! Employee or Address?
i have seen in a book about Spring(IoC) that said: "Employee is a dependent object or target", but in some websites it was vice versa.

Comment: _i have seen in a book_ which book it is?

Comment: @mallikarjun Pro Spring.

Comment: fallow the book, Employee is dependent on the address.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is confused about the terminology being similar.  Employee is *dependent* on Address.  Address is a *dependency* of Employee.

Comment: check here please https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-tutorial-constructor-injection-with-dependent-object it says Address is dependent. @jrahhali